# How to initiate revmob banner ad with exact frame and placement ID?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, revmob

I tried using the suggested code from RevMob to show a banner ad with a specific placement ID without success, tried this code:

```
RevMobAds *revmob = [RevMobAds revMobAds];
        RevMobBanner *banner = [revmob bannerWithPlacementId:@"ID_FROM_REV_MOB"];
        [banner showAd];
```

Tried even to add the following statement

```
if (IS_iPad) {
        banner.frame =  CGRectMake(0, 958, 768, 66);
    } else if (IS_WIDESCREEN){
        banner.frame = CGRectMake(0, 518, 320, 50);
    } else {
        banner.frame = CGRectMake(0, 430, 320, 50);
    }
```

but no success, the only way I could be able to show banner ads was this:

```
[RevMobAds showBannerAdWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 958, 768, 66) withDelegate:self];
```

But it didn't help to add the placement ID.

Comment: You shouldn't make a real placementID or appID public.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need to do it as the following by using the RevMobBannwerView instead:

```
RevMobAds *revmob = [RevMobAds revMobAds];
        RevMobBannerView *revBannerView = [revmob bannerViewWithPlacementId:@"ID_FROM_REV_MOB"];
        if (IS_iPad) {
            revBannerView.frame =  CGRectMake(0, 958, 768, 66);
        } else if (IS_WIDESCREEN){
            revBannerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 518, 320, 50);
        } else {
            revBannerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 430, 320, 50);
        }
        [revBannerView loadAd];
        [self.view addSubview:revBannerView];
        [self.view bringSubviewToFront:revBannerView];
```

Answer (score 1):

When I'm adding it(RevMob version 5.9) in my project. I do it like this:

```
[RevMobAds startSessionWithAppID:@"my id"];
RevMobBannerView *ad = [[RevMobAds session] bannerView]; // you must retain this object
[ad loadWithSuccessHandler:^(RevMobBannerView *banner) {
    banner.frame = CGRectMake(0, 381, 320, 50);
    [self.window.rootViewController.view addSubview:banner];
    NSLog(@"Ad loaded");
} andLoadFailHandler:^(RevMobBannerView *banner, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Ad error: %@",error);
} onClickHandler:^(RevMobBannerView *banner) {
    NSLog(@"Ad clicked");
}];
```